# OSM administrative polygons : what is the current worldwide coverage?

Tags: openstreetmap, administrative-boundaries, natural-earth, gadm

**Does OSM have a summary view of its administrative polygons coverage worldwide for each administrative level ?**

---

NaturalEarth have Countries (L0), and subdivisions (L-1) with complete (100%) coverage.

[GADM.org have a very clean summary of its coverage for L-1 to L-5](http://www.gadm.org/maps), it's super easily readable thanks to a nice visualization (see previous link and following snapshot) :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Does OSM have a similar coverage summary somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A German user has set up an englsih-german wiki page dealing with adminstrative borders, with links to the admin_0 relation and the relating wikipedia pages, as well as notes on the completeness of the data:

- http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Wambacher#International_Administrative_Boundaries

The data itself is available as shapefile or json here:

- https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

The tree view on the left can be expanded to access the sublevels, if they exist in OSM.

Comment: Update: First link, a repport on OSM, haven't downloadable links. Second link is only L0.

Comment: You can expand the nodes in the tree view. See my extended answer.

Comment: Url is outdated, page moved to https://wambachers-osm.website/boundaries/

Comment: Second link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

http://layers.openstreetmap.fr/ is what you're looking for. Has colored layers for each admin level's coverage over the whole OSM database.