# Where to find administrative L-2 polygons under open license?

Tags: administrative-boundaries, natural-earth, diva-gis, gadm

NaturalEarth provide L-0 (countries) and L-1 (sub-division) shapefiles, but no L-2 (sub-sub-division) shapefiles.

GADM.org provides L0 to L-5 data, and have a pretty good coverage for L-2 (sub-sub-division) shapefiles.

[image]

but it is forbidden for commercial use.

**Where do I find administrative L-2 polygons with near similar world coverage under open license ?**

Comment: For Open Data questions you may want to consider posting to the [Open Data (Beta) Stack Exchange](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Related to [OSM administrative polygons : what is the current worldwide coverage?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109751/)

Answer (score 2):

A German user has set up a vizualisation and export service of the boundaries inside the OpenStreetmap project:

https://osm.wno-edv-service.de/boundaries/

Clicking on the country's node on the left will open the sublevels.

Note that OSM counts the levels a bit different: OSM-level 2 is GADM-level 0

OSM data can be used commercially, as long as you mention where the data is from.

Comment: I noticed for the different naming conventions. The key is to get suitable and clean data, so your answer does help :)

Comment: I worry however that OSM data will be more instable than GADM.

Comment: You get what you paid for ...